# How to make maven project recognize xml from third party jar?

Tags: spring, datasource, jndi, applicationcontext

In my project I use a third party jar. This jar depends on jndi.xml and jndi.properties files.

Structure of the stand-alone third party jar:

```
    /
    |- TP.jar
    |- jndi.xml
    |- jndi.properties
```

Inside the applicationContext of this jar - there is a reference to the bean created in jndi.xml
This jar is built using ant and the build works fine.

I included this jar in my maven project as dependency. In my maven projects dispatcher-servlet, the TP.jar's applciation context is imported to gain access to the beans in TP.jar.

My maven project's deploy fails with the below error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [JNDIDatasource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [JNDIDatasource].
```

jndi.properties:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.xbean.spring.jndi.SpringInitialContextFactory
```

jndi.xml:

```
<beans>
<bean class="org.apache.xbean.spring.jndi.DefaultContext" id="jndi">
    <property name="entries">
        <map>
             <entry key="JNDIDatasource">
                <bean class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" singleton="false">
                    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"></property>
                    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:1433;DatabaseName=test"></property>
                    -----
                </bean>
            </entry>
              -----------
 </bean>
 --------------
</beans>
```

TP.jar applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="JNDIDatasource" />
</bean>
```

When this above applicationContext is imported in my maven project, tomcat wont start.
I am pretty badly stuck on how to resolve this and any help would be highly appreciated.

I tried adding both jndi.xml and jndi.properties to my maven project under **src/main/resources** with the hope that they will be included in my maven project's path and there by the bean might be detected. But that did not help.

Comment: does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my application.

**Application Context**

```
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd        
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            ..
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
            ">

<jee:jndi-lookup id="cdrDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/cdr_source" resource-ref="true" />

</beans>
```

**jndi.properties**

```
 java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.xbean.spring.jndi.SpringInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = classpath:/jndi.xml
```

**jndi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd      ">


    <bean id="jndi" class="org.apache.xbean.spring.jndi.DefaultContext">
        <property name="entries">
            <map>   
                <entry key="jdbc/cdr">
                    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
                        <property name="driverClassName">
                            <value>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="url">
                            <value>jdbc:jtds:sybase://server:7306/cdr</value>
                        </property>     
....
```

**Client call**

```
@Repository
public class CDRDataRetriever {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Resource(name = "cdrDataSource")
    private DataSource cdrDataSource;
```